# Relation Between Metric Function and Norm Function

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

We all know that for a metric space $(X,d)$ which is induced from a norm $(X,|| \cdot ||)$, the following is true for every $a\in X$ and $r>0$:
$$B(a,r)=a+r B(0,1)$$
My question is about the converse. If there is a metric $d$ which satisfies the above condition, will there be a norm function such that $||x||=d(x,0)$ for every $x \in X$?

Comment: You already have the norm. It only remains to prove that it is a norm, or that it may fail to be a norm.

Comment: How can we check whether it is a norm or not when d is given in a general settings?

Comment: well, what are the axioms of a norm? which of those can you prove? can you find one that is not satisfied?

Comment: Here norm means norm over a vector space. Axioms are welknown. First axiom is the non negativity condition. It is obvious. But the other two axioms are giving some pain.

Comment: A metric ball need not be convex... but a ball from a norm is.

Comment: @GEdgar we have a special kind of metric here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*sketch of proof:*

Define the candidate norm $\|x\| = d(x,0)$.

**First step:**

Let $y$ be given.
We have $B(y,r)=y+B(0,r)$ for all $r>0$,
so
$$
 d(x+y,y) < r \Leftrightarrow
 y+x \in B(y,r) \Leftrightarrow
 y+x \in y+B(0,r) \Leftrightarrow
 d(x,0) < r
$$
holds for all $x\in X, r>0$.
Thus $$
\tag{1}
d(x+y,y)=d(x,0)\text{.}$$
The triangle inequality for norms follows:

$$\|x+y\| = d(x+y, 0) \le d(x+y,y) + d(y,0) = d(x,0) + \|y\| = \|x\| + \|y\|$$

**Second step:**
similarly, we can show that
$d(\alpha x,0) = \alpha d(x,0)$
for $\alpha>0$.
Moreover, by (1) we have that
$$
  d(\alpha x,0)
  = d(0,-\alpha x)
 = |\alpha | d(0,x)
 = |\alpha | d(x,0)
$$
is true for all $\alpha<0$.

Thus homogenity follows.

Comment: edited. it holds for all $x$ and is a consequence of the set equality mentioned before that.

Comment: one way to see this: if they are different, choose $r$ the arithmetic mean of the two and apply the equivalence above

Comment: It is *not* given that $B(y,r) =  y+ B(0,r)$ but it equals $y + rB(0,1)$. Maybe adapt the argument ?

Comment: yeah but $B(0,r)=rB(0,1)$ follows. it is only a sketch of proof

Comment: It indeed follows from the $x=0$ case.

Comment: When $\alpha>0$ one has $d(\alpha x, 0)<r \Leftrightarrow \alpha x \in r B(0,1)\Leftrightarrow x\in\frac{r}{\alpha} B(0,1)= B(0,\frac{r}{\alpha})\Leftrightarrow \alpha d(x, 0)<r$, which proves positive homogeneity. To complete your proof, you need also to show that the norm induces the distance. This is a consequence of (1) as $d(x, y) = d((x-y)+y, y) = d(x-y,0) = \|x-y\|$.